# Passing multiple parameter s to a function as a object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which has input parameters as below:

```
function a(s,d,f,r,g,h,u)
```

I want to combine all the input parameters into one object and pass it in to the function. I have to write a set function instead of using options. Any idea regarding this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use an array: `[s,d,f,r,g,h,u]` or make an object: `{s: s,d: d,f: f,r: r,g: g,h: h,u: u}`

```
function a(obj)
{
...
}
```

in your function you can access the members of an array by this way:

`obj[number]` e.g. `obj[0]` will be the `s`, `obj[3]` will be the `r`

and if you need to make an object you can access the elements just writing `obj.name`
e.g. `obj.d` will be the `d` and `obj.h` will be the `h`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass one argument to the function then use

```
function fn(arr) { }
var arr = [s,d,f,r,g,h,u];

fn(arr);
```

Alternatively, If you want to pass the same number of arguments but still use one variable for it then use

```
function fn (s,d,f,r,g,h,u) { }

var arr = [s,d,f,r,g,h,u];
fn.call(null, arr);
```

`fn.call` It will pass the elements of the array as the parameters of the function

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of input parameters and can pass to function

```
var array = new Array()
array[0] = parameter1
array[1] = parameter2
```

function(array){

//use parameters here like array[0]

}

Answer (score 0):

...rather than passing the object that you'll create, you could make use of the default `arguments` parameter available to  all functions and go from there.

```
function a(){alert(arguments.length)}

a(1,2); // alerts 2
a(1,2,3); // alerts 3
a(1); // alerts 1
```

Hope this helps.